# List Exception caused by trigger

Tags: trigger, dml, exception

I have some code in a trigger that works when tested, and works in my sandbox, when I get it into production every time something happens where the trigger should go off, I get this error:

```
Apex script unhandled trigger exception by user/organization: 005d0000001ryBy/00Dd0000000ezLZ

updatePrMEnCCeO: execution of AfterUpdate

caused by: System.ListException: Duplicate id in list: a00d000000ND7HtAAL

Trigger.updatePrMEnCCeO: line 29, column 1
```

The basic logic of what's happening is that there are up to 3 sObjects in play here, the first would be a `Center__c` sObject (there is trigger to change the `Center_Owner__c` on the Programs sObject), the child of that is the `Programs__c` sObject, and the child of that is the `Applications__c` sObject. So if someone changes the center owner on the `Center__c`, it'll go down and find all associated programs and change the center owner, and then THIS trigger happens that will find all associated applications with the current program and change the center owner. The problem is I get that error whenever it happens. It seems to work fine changing `program_manager__c` or `enrollment_counselor__c` directly from the `Programs__c` sObject, but it fails out with `Center_Owner__c`.

I'm thinking it has something to do with the two loops, because obviously in production there's a lot more data than in the sandbox, is there a way around this?  So in the interest of brevity I'll just include the loop, here's the offending loop:

```
trigger updatePrMEnCCeO on Programs__c (after update) {
    List<Programs__c> prOld = trigger.old;

    List<Application__c> app = [SELECT Program_Manager__c, Enrollment_Counselor__c, Center_Owner__c, Id from
         Application__c WHERE Programs__c=:prOld[0].id];

    List<Application__c> upApp=new List<Application__c>();

for (Programs__c edited : trigger.new) { 
   if ((prOld[0].program_manager_lookup__c != edited.program_manager__c) || (prOld[0].Enrollment_Counselor__c != edited.Enrollment_Counselor__c) || (prOld[0].Center_Owner__c!=edited.Center_Owner__c)) {
         for (Integer i=0; i<app.size(); i++) {
            app[i].Program_Manager__c=edited.Program_Manager_lookup__c;
            app[i].Enrollment_Counselor__c=edited.Enrollment_Counselor__c;
            app[i].Center_Owner__c=edited.Center_Owner__c; 
            upApp.add(app[i]);
         }
    }
}
update upApp;
}
```

As requested here is the test class:

```
@isTest
public with sharing class updatePrMEnCCeOTest {
public static testMethod void updatePrMEnCCeOTest () {
test.starttest();
Account a=new account();
a.name='testschool';
insert a;

User u= new user();
u.username='test654984654@gmail.com';
u.lastname='testlast';
u.email='test@gmail.com';
u.CommunityNickname='test';
u.TimeZoneSidKey='America/New_York';
u.LocaleSidKey='en_US';
u.EmailEncodingKey='ISO-8859-1';
List<profile> p=[SELECT id FROM Profile WHERE profile.name='Administrator'];
u.ProfileId=p[0].id;
u.LanguageLocaleKey='en_US';
u.alias='test';
insert u;

Centers__c cent=new Centers__c();
cent.name='test';
insert cent;

Programs__c Prog = new Programs__c();
prog.Centers_LOOKUP__c=cent.id;
prog.start_date__c=date.parse('08/01/2014');
insert prog;

Contact con=new Contact();
con.LastName='Test University';
insert con;

List<Application__c> addapp=new List<Application__c>();
for (integer i=0;i<201;i++) {
    Application__c App = new Application__c();
    app.Contact__c=con.id;
    addapp.add(app);
}   
insert addapp;

prog.program_manager_lookup__c=u.id;
prog.enrollment_counselor__c=u.id;
prog.Center_Owner__c=u.id;

update prog;


System.assertEquals(u.id,prog.program_manager_lookup__c);
System.assertEquals(u.id,prog.enrollment_counselor__c);
System.assertEquals(u.id,prog.Center_Owner__c);

test.stoptest();
}
```

}

Any idea? Maybe a Map<> (I don't quite know how to use them though)

Comment: Can you show us your test class?  And it passes when you are in your sandbox?

Comment: In your other code, does anything else add to the **upApp** list?

Comment: can you paste the full trigger, I see prOld[0] is this a list/set? What is the SOQL behind it.

Comment: dphil nothing else adds to the upApp list, this is the only trigger that touches the app. rao I've edited the rest of the trigger in. EricSSH I can paste in the test class but it's literally just making one of each object and then doing a system assert.

Comment: It would be normal to compare corresponding entries in the Trigger.old and Trigger.new collections. While stepping through Trigger.new you are always comparing with the first entry in Trigger.old. The error you are getting is just one symptom of the problem. Needs a rewrite and a test case that inserts more than one `Programs__c` object to indicate that it works with more than one object at a time.

Comment: I think you need to create a Set of Ids, and then make them into a Map

Comment: @EricSSH I've added the test class. As for making the map, I'm not sure how, is it just `Map<string, Application__c> appmap=[soql query]();` how do I then go through it in a loop if it's not ordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may want to start a new thread after this post, because after what Keith said they most likely will not answer questions on this one.. So this can be a start, but do some more research and start a new thread..

```
Set < id > validSet = new set < id > (); 
  for (Program__c p: Trigger.new)//Creating a set of ids loop
  {
     if (p.Center_Owner__c != null) //might wanna check this condition  
     {
        validSet.add(p.Center_Owner__c );  //Adding    
     }      
  }
// Get Application__c into a list...
List < Application__c > applicationList = [Select Your query IN: validSet];
// and make a map    
 Map < String, Application__c > applicationMap = new Map < String, Application__c > ();   
  for (Application__c application: applicationList)
  {
     applicationMap.put(application.contact__c, application);
  }
```

Comment: thank you for the start, I think I kind of understand it. I kind of wish people would still answer after Keith's answer since I thought I was comparing the first entry in trigger old for differences in each entry of trigger new. but c'est la internets :)

Comment: It is annoying sometimes, but I understand why they do it.. Good luck!

Comment: @mikesalty I'm feeling like the bad guy here... I should have found an example that checks for changes between Trigger.old and Trigger.new and included a link to it to help you get further. Someone should post "the 10 common trigger patterns" and we can all just use them as a starting point. If you can make the question (this or a new one) clear enough you will get people posting answers including code whatever the comment thread is - and you get to choose who was most helpful so in some ways you are in control.

Comment: @KeithC - Sorry man, I'm not trying to say you're the bad guy, it may have sounded more frustrated than I actually was. I do understand why the answer would have killed the thread, and I don't want the work done for me. I'm still learning, a more explained version of your comment would have been helpful is all I meant. No worries, no hard feelings, and I hope you don't feel like the bad guy :)

Comment: @mikesalty No need for you to apologise and no hard feelings. Hope you are making some headway.